# how to remove table view section header using prototype cell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I set my table view header section in interface builder by using prototype cell like this

[image]

here is the end result of this table view header section

[image]

the data is actually dynamic, and if the section available is only one (let say just finance), I want the table view header section to be not exist, just show up the name of the person. below is the simplified code I use.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var sectionMember : [Department]?

    var abcd = 2


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        let IT = Department(name: "IT", member: ["joko", "santi","pipin","candra"])
        let finance = Department(name: "Finance & Accounting", member: ["ririn","andri","bagus","reyhan"])
        let security = Department(name: "security", member: ["anto","budi","rudi"])
        let purchasing = Department(name: "Purchasing", member: ["lulu","rina","santi"])

        sectionMember = [IT,finance,security, purchasing]
        //sectionMember = [IT]


    }



}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate {

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return (sectionMember?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sectionMember![section].member.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! TableViewCell

        let departmentMember = sectionMember![indexPath.section].member[indexPath.row]

        cell.memberOfDepartment = departmentMember

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


        if abcd == 1 {
            return nil
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! HeaderCell
            cell.department = sectionMember![section].name
            return cell
        }



    }




}
```

to simplify the code I use variable `abcd` , if `abcd = 1` I want that section header to be hidden/remove/not exist, but if abcd is not 1 then show up the header section.

in the method `viewForHeaderInSection` , I `return nil` if `abcd = 1`, but the result is just still show the header section, but the color is grey, I don't know why it is grey color not pink color like in the storyboard. so how to get rid of that grey section like below ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you have given nil to header if there is only one section, but give the height too

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if sectionMember?.count ?? 0 == 1 {
        return 0.0
    }
    else {
        return your height
    }
}
```

also,
your function

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (sectionMember?.count)!
}
```

never use bang operator like this.. unwrap it with a default value

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sectionMember?.count ?? 0
}
```